# Language switch works after 2 clicks on a language

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem with the language switch. I have 7 languages on my website.

[image]

If I click on `FR`, the page is translated correctly.
If I click on `NL` also, the page is translated correctly.

However, If I click on `EN`, nothing is happening... **I have to click 2 times** **to display the page in English**. I don't understand why?

Then...

If I click on `DE`, the page is translated correctly.

But, If I click on `ES`, nothing is happening... I have the same probleme in English. I have to click 2 times to display the page in Spanish.

In `IT` et `PT` , I don't have any problems.

Here is an idea of the file -> **auth-layout.component.html**

```
<div class="languageSelect">
   <a href="#" *ngFor="let l of supportedLangs; let i = index" (click)="switchLanguage(l); false; ">
       {{ l | uppercase}}  <!-- FR | NL | EN | DE | ES | IT | PT -->
   </a>
</div>
```

In the file -> **auth-layout.component.ts** I have this in JS, I don't see where is the error?

if you have an idea, I am interested, because I am stuck.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth-layout',
  templateUrl: './auth-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth-layout.component.scss']
})
export class AuthLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  
  supportedLangs;

  constructor(
    public _router: Router, 
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private LS: LocalStoreService,
    public _location: Location
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.supportedLangs = ['fr', 'nl', 'en', 'de', 'es', 'it', 'pt'];
  }


  switchLanguage(lang){
    if(lang == 'uk'){
      lang = 'en';
    }
    this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
        this.LS.setItem('LX_Current_Language', event.lang);
        console.log("LELOG OK X : " + this.LS.getItem('LX_Current_Language'));
    });
    console.log("LELOG OK A : " + this.LS.getItem('LX_Current_Language'));
    this.translate.use(lang);
    this.refresh();
  }

  refresh(): void {
    this._router.navigateByUrl("/refresh", { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
        this._router.navigate([decodeURI(this._location.path())]);
    });
  }

}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If `translate.onLangChange` is a Subject that's updated when you call `translate.use(lang)` you may need to subscribe to only the first emitted value, otherwise the subscription function might continue being triggered for the languages you clicked before. Have you tried :

```
this.translate.onLangChange.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(...
```

Comment: Hello Guillaumme, thank you for your help. I tried `this.translate.onLangChange.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {` but I alway have the same problem.  when I click on English, I have to click twice before the page is displayed in English.